# How to setup iis in Azure web app service with Net Core 2 app?

Tags: azure, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I develop simple Web Api on Net Core 2 and add Angular app to it (inside wwwroot folder) and publish it from my VS 2017 IDE to Azure Web App Service. All work fine, but when I reload page of my app in browser, server can't find route. So It often happens when iis not setup for SPA, It's described in https://angular.io/guide/deployment, I must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have. How I can setup server node of iis in Azure Web App Service (web.config in Net Core 2 was deleted).

Comment: You may refer this GitHub link: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot achieve this.

**Cause:** Azure App Services runs IIS so it behaves mostly the same as local IIS, routing requests using a native module called AspNetCoreModule. So, it needs your published `web.config` file. Even though you deleted the web.config file, Azure would also generate a new web.config file to be used.(Though I don't understand why you delete the `web.config` file)

**Solution:**
Even you can upload the web.config file to Azure again, I'm afraid of that it will be ignored and doesn't work. So, I suggest you redeploy your website which contains `web.config` file to Azure and configure it well.

Additional: Azure Web App service is a kind of PaaS. So, if you want to install IIS manually, you can choose to host your website on a Windows Azure VM.